# python-telegram-bot: AttributeError: 'ExtBot' object has no attribute 'reply_to'

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

i want to make answer on my message or other users, but i stuck on the error.

> await context.bot.reply_to(update.message, "NO.")
> AttributeError: 'ExtBot' object has no attribute 'reply_to'

I tried to get message with update.message

```
async def lockdown(update: telegram.Update, context: ext.ContextTypes):
    sender_id = update.message.from_user.id
    if sender_id == 7472:
        print("YEA")  
    else:
        await context.bot.reply_to(update.message, "NO.")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. The class [`ExtBot`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.extbot.html#extbot) does not have a method named `reply_to`. You're probably looking for [`Message.reply_text`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_text) or [`Bot.send_message`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message).

Please be sure to read the [PTB tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---Your-first-Bot) and to have a look at the [examples](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/examples.html).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.